# Is it possible to set dimension value resources as a calculation of other dimension values in android XML?

Tags: android, xml

for example I have

```
<dimen name="dimA">45dp</dimen>
```

can I define another dimension value that's calculated based on the first one:

```
<dimen name="dimB">dimA * 2</dimen>
```

or do it in the layout xml as such:

```
android:text_size="@dimensions/dimA * 2"
```

I know this particular syntax is incorrect, is there a syntax that makes it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

programtically you can do it.  In xml layout you cant ...so why not just get the dimension programatically and do your calculation ?

if you really need something like that an ant script might help you but thats really complicated for such a little change.